# Typescript: Using an array of generics to create an array of object with generic in the order of the generic list

Tags: typescript, generics

I would like to create a class with an unlimited list of generic types and a parameter, which is an array of another class with a generic.

The generics of the class inside the array should be in the order of the generic list of the main class.

```
class OtherClass<T> {
    public readonly something: T
}

class Class<T extends any[]> {
    public readonly parameter: [OtherClass<T[0]>, OtherClass<T[1]>, ...]
}
```

Example:

```
const c = new Class<[string, number]>();

// should be string
c.parameter[0].something;

// should be number
c.parameter[1].something

const c1 = new Class<[number, string, SomeClass, someOtherClass]>();

// Should be number
c1.parameter[0].something;

// Should be string
c1.parameter[1].something;

// Should be SomeClass
c1.parameter[2].something;

// Should be SomeOtherClass
c1.parameter[3].something;
```

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to create a [mapped type](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/advanced-types.html#mapped-types) from `T` where there indexes of the array are the keys, and the values are the class wrapping the entry at that index.

```
class Class<T extends any[]> {
  public readonly parameter: {
    [Index in keyof T]: OtherClass<T[Index]>
  }
}
```

Now the rest works just like you expect:

```
const c = new Class<[string, number]>();
const a1: string = c.parameter[0].something;
const a2: number = c.parameter[1].something;

const c1 = new Class<[number, string, SomeClass, SomeOtherClass]>();
const b1: number = c1.parameter[0].something;
const b2: string = c1.parameter[1].something;
const b3: SomeClass = c1.parameter[2].something;
const b4: SomeOtherClass = c1.parameter[3].something;
```

[Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/MYGwhgzhAEDyAuALApgJwMLigHgCoD5oBvAKGnOgAcBXAIxAEthpVkwATAewDsQBPaBE4BbZEgbcA5gEIAXNFwkAviRKhIMAMojkmDcTJU6jZqw49+0eH0rJ5EeKgmToAXmgByIaOjqoH5VU-LR0EFAwsGFJyGnomFjYuXgFrW3tHZzdPb2RfSICVNUjoPRxcaGQAD3hkbnYYMG4+AG0AXUJoozjTRIsBSjBUMFEa1DkDCmhmgEk6qugJaABrZD5OADMFVvkwtFKIPBm5yvbDFUK1HgdfLO5kAHcSyOxmhycpABpobmphWjR2gAKACUAG5LtxrmAAIzpd4udzAAB0AyGIzQzQADK0kTlxFJwcArvBoGAAEzyH5-NBZZGo4ZiDHQnF4xDOcEQ67AaG3B5PDQvKn-VBfN7OL7aUT7CWhJB7SJAsGckm0WHfX7C2nQlGDBmjLEsnT4ySE4nQWgUwQZKRanVoxmoZrM3FGtkE5XmgDM8klumKiO19PRjrJhpGbpNHtoABYfbLwvtbUGHc1PWGxBHQUA)